# Maven Assembly: Introduce java doc from a separate project

Tags: maven, javadoc

I have an assembly descriptor to generate a separate package for our documentation, including the javadoc. It contains the following to include generated javadoc from the same project it's 
 running in (assembly is a subproject from core):

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>../core/target/site/apidocs</directory>
    <outputDirectory>javadoc</outputDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
    </includes>
</fileSet>
```

But how can I include java doc from a completely separate project which I do not know the path on the file system to, just have the .m2 repo let's say. I have tried the following but it does not seem to do anything:

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <includes>
            <include>com.company:company-utils:*:javadoc</include>
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory>apidocs-util</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks

Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the javadoc of the project that you are interested has been installed/deployed to local/remote repository, you can get it into your assembly by adding it as a dependency in your pom with `javadoc` as `<classifier>`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>company-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

The following snippet in the assembly descriptor (*without the classifier*) worked for me.

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <includes>
            <include>com.company:company-utils</include>
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory>apidocs-util</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked... I had forgotten the dependency in the POM.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to create the javadoc within a different project than the current one. It is created during the default release cycle. So need to make a separate assembly for that. Or if you think you need something supplemental apart from the javadoc check the [documentation for the maven-javadoc-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html)

BTW: Never make packaging from a different package than your own, cause that will produce trouble.

Comment: Maybe there was a misunderstanding. I do not wanna create the javadoc from the other project, I just wish to bundle the (already) generated javadoc into a doc zip file as a deliverable to a customer.